# exception "unhashable type: 'list'" while following Mozilla django tutorial

Tags: django, django-models

I'm working through Mozilla's excellent Django tutorial at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django, and have introduced a bug I can't find.

The tutorial sets up a simple library catalog system. In a previous section the tutorial setup a book detail view, where I could view all instances of a book with a given id by going to:

```
http://192.168.0.28:8000/catalog/book/<book-id>
```

This was working fine, but I've somehow managed to trash it. When trying to get to `http://192.168.0.28:8000/catalog/book/4` I now get:

```
TypeError at /catalog/book/4

unhashable type: 'list'

Request Method:     GET Request URL:    http://192.168.0.28:8000/catalog/book/4 Django Version:     2.1.1 Exception Type:   TypeError Exception Value:  unhashable type: 'list' Exception Location:     /home/mike/anaconda3/envs/miketestenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py in get_order_by, line 287 Python Executable:     /home/mike/anaconda3/envs/miketestenv/bin/python Python Version:
    3.6.6 Python Path:  

['/home/mike/Projects/locallibrary',  '/home/mike/anaconda3/envs/miketestenv/lib/python36.zip',  '/home/mike/anaconda3/envs/miketestenv/lib/python3.6',  '/home/mike/anaconda3/envs/miketestenv/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',  '/home/mike/anaconda3/envs/miketestenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages']

Server time:    Tue, 16 Oct 2018 11:20:39 +0100 Error during template rendering

In template /home/mike/Projects/locallibrary/catalog/templates/base_generic.html, error at line 0 unhashable type: 'list' 1     <!DOCTYPE html> 2   <html lang="en"> 3  <head> 4      {% block title %}<title>Local Library</title>{% endblock %} 5       <meta charset="utf-8"> 6    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 7      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous"> 8       <!-- Add additional CSS in static file
--> 9     {% load static %} 10    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
```

Book id number 4 is a valid book id. The same error happens for all book ids.

The relevant section in urls.py is :

```
path('book/<int:pk>', views.BookDetailView.as_view(), name='book-detail'),
```

From views.py:

```
class BookDetailView(generic.DetailView):

    model = Book
```

The base_generic.html template is fine, and works for all other types of pages. The problem occurs when importing the book_detail template. book_detail.py looks like the below:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Title: {{ book.title }}</h1>

<p><strong>Author:</strong> <a href="">{{ book.author }}</a></p> <!-- author detail link not yet defined -->
  <p><strong>Summary:</strong> {{ book.summary }}</p>
<p><strong>ISBN:</strong> {{ book.isbn }}</p> 
<p><strong>Language:</strong> {{ book.language }}</p>  
<p><strong>Genre:</strong> {% for genre in book.genre.all %} {{ genre }}{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}{% endfor %}</p> 
<div style="margin-left:20px;margin-top:20px">
    <h4>Copies</h4>
    {% for copy in book.bookinstance_set.all %}
        <hr>
        <p class="{% if copy.status == 'a' %}text-success{% elif copy.status == 'm' %}text-danger{% else %}text-warning{% endif %}">{{ copy.get_status_display }}</p>
        {% if copy.status != 'a' %}
            <p><strong>Due to be returned:</strong> {{copy.due_back}}</p>
        {% endif %}
        <p><strong>Imprint:</strong> {{copy.imprint}}</p>
        <p class="text-muted"><strong>Id:</strong> {{copy.id}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

If I remove the lines from

```
{% for copy in book.bookinstance_set.all %}
```

to

```
{% endfor %}
```

the exception is cleared,

If I now go to the python manage.py shell:

```
from catalog.models import Book
from catalog.models import BookInstance
```

I can see valid data in Book:

```
In [8]: Book.objects.all()
Out[8]: <QuerySet [<Book: Hitchikers Guide>, <Book: So Long, and thanks for all the fish>, <Book: Harry potter 1>, <Book: Harry potter 2>, <Book: Oreilly Django>, <Book: another oreilly book>]>
```

I get a "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'" error when trying to list BookInstance items (even after deleting all BookInstances) :

```
In [13]: BookInstance.objects.all() Out[13]:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) ~/anaconda3/envs/miketestenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    700                 type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
    701                 deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
--> 702             printer.pretty(obj)
    703             printer.flush()
    704             return stream.getvalue()

~/anaconda3/envs/miketestenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.py in pretty(self, obj)
    398                         if cls is not object \
    399                                 and callable(cls.__dict__.get('__repr__')):
--> 400                             return _repr_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
    401
    402             return _default_pprint(obj, self, cycle)

~/anaconda3/envs/miketestenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.py in _repr_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
    693     """A pprint that just redirects to the normal repr function."""
    694     # Find newlines and replace them with p.break_()
--> 695     output = repr(obj)
    696     for idx,output_line in enumerate(output.splitlines()):
    697         if idx:

~/anaconda3/envs/miketestenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in __repr__(self)
    242
    243     def __repr__(self):
--> 244         data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
    245         if len(data) > REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE:
    246             data[-1] = "...(remaining elements truncated)..."

~/anaconda3/envs/miketestenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in __iter__(self)
    266                - Responsible for turning the rows into model objects.
    267         """
--> 268         self._fetch_all()
    269         return iter(self._result_cache)
    270

~/anaconda3/envs/miketestenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in _fetch_all(self)    1184     def _fetch_all(self):    1185         if self._result_cache is None:
-> 1186             self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))    1187         if self._prefetch_related_lookups and not self._prefetch_done:    1188    self._prefetch_related_objects()

~/anaconda3/envs/miketestenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in __iter__(self)
     52         # Execute the query. This will also fill compiler.select, klass_info,
     53         # and annotations.
---> 54         results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
     55         select, klass_info, annotation_col_map = (compiler.select, compiler.klass_info,
     56                                                   compiler.annotation_col_map)

~/anaconda3/envs/miketestenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py in execute_sql(self, result_type, chunked_fetch, chunk_size)    1050   result_type = result_type or NO_RESULTS    1051         try:
-> 1052             sql, params = self.as_sql()    1053             if not sql:    1054                 raise EmptyResultSet

~/anaconda3/envs/miketestenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py in as_sql(self, with_limits, with_col_aliases)
    447         refcounts_before = self.query.alias_refcount.copy()
    448         try:
--> 449             extra_select, order_by, group_by = self.pre_sql_setup()
    450             for_update_part = None
    451             # Is a LIMIT/OFFSET clause needed?

~/anaconda3/envs/miketestenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py in pre_sql_setup(self)
     49         """
     50         self.setup_query()
---> 51         order_by = self.get_order_by()
     52         self.where, self.having = self.query.where.split_having()
     53         extra_select = self.get_extra_select(order_by, self.select)

~/anaconda3/envs/miketestenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py in get_order_by(self)
    285             descending = order == 'DESC'
    286
--> 287             if col in self.query.annotation_select:
    288                 # Reference to expression in SELECT clause
    289                 order_by.append((

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Can anyone give me some idea where to go next with this? I can obviously start the tutorial again, but that won't get me any closer to understanding what I've done wrong, and learning how to find fix this problem in future. Thanks!

As requested by Bruno, the models.py looks like the below:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from datetime import date

# Create your models here.

class Genre(models.Model):
    """Model representing a book genre."""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Enter a book genre (e.g. Science Fiction)')

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return self.name

from django.urls import reverse # Used to generate URLs by reversing the URL patterns

class Book(models.Model):
    """Model representing a book (but not a specific copy of a book)."""
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    # Foreign Key used because book can only have one author, but authors can have multiple books
    # Author as a string rather than object because it hasn't been declared yet in the file
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    summary = models.TextField(max_length=1000, help_text='Enter a brief description of the book')
    isbn = models.CharField('ISBN', max_length=13, help_text='13 Character <a href="https://www.isbn-international.org/content/what-isbn">ISBN number</a>')

    # ManyToManyField used because genre can contain many books. Books can cover many genres.
    # Genre class has already been defined so we can specify the object above.
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, help_text='Select a genre for this book')

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Returns the url to access a detail record for this book."""
        return reverse('book-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def display_genre(self):
        """Create a string for the Genre. This is required to display genre in Admin."""
        return ', '.join(genre.name for genre in self.genre.all()[:3])

    display_genre.short_description = 'Genre'    

import uuid # Required for unique book instances

class BookInstance(models.Model):
    """Model representing a specific copy of a book (i.e. that can be borrowed from the library)."""
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, help_text='Unique ID for this particular book across whole library')
    book = models.ForeignKey('Book', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True) 
    imprint = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    due_back = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    borrower = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

    @property
    def is_overdue(self):
        if self.due_back and date.today() > self.due_back:
            return True
        return False    

    LOAN_STATUS = (
        ('m', 'Maintenance'),
        ('o', 'On loan'),
        ('a', 'Available'),
        ('r', 'Reserved'),
    )

    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=LOAN_STATUS,
        blank=True,
        default='m',
        help_text='Book availability',
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['due_back'],
        permissions = (("can_mark_returned", "Set book as returned"),)  

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return f'{self.id} ({self.book.title})'

class Author(models.Model):
    """Model representing an author."""
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_of_death = models.DateField('Died', null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['last_name', 'first_name']

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Returns the url to access a particular author instance."""
        return reverse('author-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return f'{self.last_name}, {self.first_name}'
```

Comment: You posted a lot of details but obviously not the useful ones.  Please post your models code. I suspect something wrong with your model's 'ordering' meta.

Comment: Typical! Thanks for the question Bruno. I've pasted the models code into the question

Answer (score 3):

You have a stray comma after the definition of `ordering` in BookInstance, which turns it into a tuple containing a list. Remove the comma.

Comment: Beat me by a couple seconds <g>

Comment: Thank you - both of you - so much. There's no way I'd have found this. It's much appreciated